# Adding a GitHub repo to Google Cloud data lab instance (multiple repos?)

Tags: git, google-cloud-datalab

Starting with Cloud Datalab, have the initial instance up and found the git repo. I want to add an existing Repo the has a project in it from Github,. Looked at the info on adding a remote from GitHub but the second line says click on "get started" that does not exist as far as I can tell I guess because I have a git repo (the default one) so I'm thinking I can only have one and I must wipe out the current one? That, off hand, does not seem to make sense? I have many repos that I may want to use that reside on Github? What do I need to do? What am I missing?

Also noted that I'm not supposed to have data in the repo (licence ) I do have sample data for convenience.. comments appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

So it seems that in the current beta version of DataLab that one can only use the default provided git repo. It does not seem possible to replace the Git repo as otherwise supported by app-engine/Compute engine..

Correct me if I'm wrong.